Unable to use trigram search with "tsquery", despite pg_trgm being installed
Hi I get issues with django being unable to run any trigram searches. I get errors such as
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: unknown <<-> tsquery

and

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying % tsquery

and before you suggest it, the pg_trgm extension is installed!
django=> SELECT * FROM pg_extension;
  oid  | extname | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion | extconfig | extcondition 
-------+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------
 13659 | plpgsql |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.0        |           | 
 17002 | pg_trgm |    16388 |         2200 | t              | 1.6        |           | 
(2 rows)

I installed it via a custom migration.
Here is the block which is calling it:

object_list = Quote.objects.annotate(
    distance=TrigramWordDistance('quote_text', query),
).filter(distance__lte=0.7).order_by('distance')

If anyone can shed some light on why this may be happening I would appreciate it.

Why are you using a tsquery? A trigram is used for text

Wow I am a moron. Thanks for your help.
